# AndroidStudio: The text of my build gradle is gray

Tags: android-studio

[image: the text of my build gradle are gray]

the text of mt build gradle are gray, It bothers me to work on the Android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to Settings | Editor | File Types, make sure that "*.gradle" is present in the list of registered patterns for "Groovy", and that there are no .gradle file names in the list of registered patterns for "Text".